# Use a return type stored in enum in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, types

I create following enum:

```
enum class Rule(val returnType: KClass<*>) {
  A(Boolean::class),
  B(Integer::class)
}
```

When I use it like `val y = Rule.A.returnType`, the type of the resultValue is `KClass<*>` of course. But I don't want that, I want the real type, so for A it's `KClass<Boolean>`.

Is there a way to to achieve this without casting it myself?

---

Why do I want this? I am trying to build an easy to use rule engine. At the moment I have following code:

```
interface Evaluator {
  operator fun <T> invoke(rule: Rule): T
}
```

and I can use it like:

```
fun createEvaluatorX(process: Evaluator) =
  when (process<Boolean>(Rule.A)) {
    true -> when (process<Integer>(Rule.B)) {
      when 1 -> // another rule (etc)
      when 2 -> ..
      else ->
    }
    false -> ..
  }
```

It would be nice if the Rules itself defined the return type instead of doing it inline. Especially when you use the same rule multiple times (in different evaluators). As enum classes cannot have type parameters, I am trying to work around this problem by defining a KClass in the enum...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve on a bigger level? You could definitely use a generic sealed class instead of the enum, but maybe it's not necessary depending on what you're trying to do

Comment: Added explanation to the why of the question

Comment: @JacobvanLingen "As enum classes cannot have type parameters" – have you tried [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Enum *types* can have type parameters, but enum *instances* cannot. But Kotlin has `sealed` classes, which offer many of the same benefits that enums do:

```
sealed interface Rule<T> 
class RuleA: Rule<Boolean>
class RuleB: Rule<Int>

fun evaluate(rule: Rule<T>) = when (rule) {
  is RuleA -> // call RuleA-method returning Boolean
  is RuleB -> // call RuleB-method returning Int
  // no need for an else block as long as you hit all `Rule` subtypes
}
```